# Java Rest constructor inheritance

Tags: java, rest, jersey, resteasy

Im getting this problem in my constructor i want to be able to take supplierName from the supplier class and add it to product.

```
public class Product {

    private long id;
    private long barcode;
    private String description;
    private String zone;
    private int quantity;

    Supplier supplierName;


    public Product(){


    }

    public Product(long id, long barcode, String description, String zone,
                   int quantity, Supplier supplierName) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.barcode = barcode;
        this.description = description;
        this.zone = zone;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.supplierName = supplierName;

    }
```

But the problem lies when i get to my product service class

```
public class ProductService {

    private Map<Long, Product> products = DatabaseClass.getProducts();

    public ProductService(){
        products.put(1L,new Product(1,1,"Lighter","Gift",5000,"Supplier1"));
        products.put(2L,new Product(2,2,"Lighter","Gift",3500,"supplier2"));

    }
```

its giving me an error for the `supplier1` & `supplier2` .

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could add the error you are receiving to your question — it should include a line number of where the problem is occuring

Comment: Remove arguements to match 'Product'

Comment: Can you share what `Supplier` looks like?

Comment: Well, `String` and `Supplier` aren't compatible, i.e. a string is not a supplier:`new Product(1,1, "Lighter","Gift",5000,"Supplier1")`

Comment: Whenever you get an error, never say only "I get an error". Error messages contain important information about the problem. First, try to understand what the error message is yourself. Google for the exact error message and you'll likely already find useful information. If you decide to post here, include the exact error message, so that we can tell you what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you edit the formatting of your code, you can clearly see you try to parse the Strings `"Supplier1"` and `"supplier2"` to the constructor, which accepts the `Supplier` as the object type.

If you have a defined class `Supplier`, change the constructor call to:

```
products.put(2L,new Product(2,2, "Lighter","Gift",3500,new Supplier(...)));
```

Or if the supplier is supposed to be the String, change its declaration and the constructor.

```
private String supplier;

public Product(long id, long barcode, String description, String zone, int quantity, String supplier) { .... }
```

---

The conclusion in all the cases is: *Please, DO formatting!* :)

Answer (score 0):

You are giving String in `"Supplier1"` and `Supplier2`, while constructor expects Object `"Supplier"`